# Почему не грузятся изображения?

Tags: python, django

Модель для аватарки

```
class UserReg(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User)
    avatar=models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='users/')
```

Форма

```
class UserProfil(forms.ModelForm):
    avatar = forms.ImageField()
    class Meta:
     model = UserReg
     fields = ('avatar', )
```

Вылетает "MultiValueDictKeyError at /auth/registration/", соответственно если проверяю request.FILES['avatar'] то значение None

Почему не отправляются изображения/файлы???
Я понял должно быть 2 основных момента:
    1. Форма должна отправляться методом POST method="post"
    2.

В форме выбрано поле ImageField, что я забыл?

Comment: Вероятнее всего форма должна быть [Multipart/form-data](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipart/form-data). Покажите шаблон и вьюху

Comment: Вы правы, забыл про enctype="multipart/form-data"